# Assigning Primitive-type vs Composite-type to a Variable

Tags: javascript, variables, types, composite, primitive

When you assign a primitive-type such as a number, string, or boolean to a variable in JavaScript *(or any language for that matter)* it opens up a slot in memory, places it in, and puts a label on it to be referenced later, correct?

```
var a = 1;
var b = 'foobar';
var c = false;
var d;

// What our memory would happen to look like:
var_a => 0x00 [1         ]
var_b => 0x01 ["foobar"  ]
var_c => 0x02 [false     ]
var_d => 0x03 [undefined ]
```

Now here is my question, how are composite-types such as arrays, functions, or objects stored in memory? I heard that objects are created somewhere off in memory and the variable only contains a reference address to this object. How is that possible? From the memory table I typed out above it seems like memory tables can only contain a single value.

Is there like special slots in memory for composite-types? Are arrays and functions stored the same way as objects *(eg by reference)*?

Comment: This depends on the implementation very much. You can read about [V8 design](https://developers.google.com/v8/design) and see that objects are similar to more traditional implementations. I wouldn't be surprised if Arrays and functions are optimized even more.

Comment: js (v8 here) doesn't use memory like you describe.there are at least two more layer of abstraction between the var and ram. About everything but numbers and strings are stored "by ref". In short: different engines can vary in the amount of ram they consume executing the code you posted.

Comment: That is true but it's so abstract and resources on this are very vague. I've started looking at Java so I can learn more about memory, how it works, and memory-management but I keep second guessing my knowledge about JavaScript or anything I've learned for that matter.

Comment: @W3Geek: JavaScript is quite similar to Java when it comes to memory management - objects are mutable and passed as reference-values, while primitves are not. For learning about memory management, you should use a lower-level language like C or C++.

Comment: @Bergi If and after studying Java I plan on learning a C# or C++ so I can dig in and see how memory really works. Since I'm a web developer this isn't something I need to know but if I do, it'd come as a big benefit. I'd have an understanding of scripting languages on a much lower-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> objects are created somewhere off in memory and the variable only contains a reference address to this object.

Yes.

> How is that possible? From the memory table I typed out above it seems like memory tables can only contain a single value.

A reference address (called a "pointer") *is* a single value.

> Is there like special slots in memory for composite-types?

Yes. Composites, also called "struct"s, can contain multiple values (but a fixed amout of them), like "a string for the name, a reference to the next property, and a field for the value" for a single link when describing an object as a linked list. The high-level JavaScript objects are stored as a multitude of different structures joined together to represent the data.

> Are arrays and functions stored the same way as objects (eg by reference)?

Yes. However, their data structures differ, they're optimized on different things.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. Thank you for your answer on this. Thinking about now, this is why objects can represent real-life entities such as a person, bank account or car where as primitive data simply cannot *(not as easily anyway)*. Composite data is made up of several primitives.